# I need something and I'm not sure if it's a service registry

Tags: microservices

I have the following situation, which seems to be coming up in multiple teams/services in our Microservices architecture.

We have Service called "Program". A call can be made to create a new program, the first thing it does is do the basic initialization of a program and then fires and event saying "Program Initialized". Then any number of services will see that event and do some jobs, when they are done, they fire their events saying they are done. The Program service is monitoring all these events and once they are all completed, it will possibly do some more final work that needs to be done and then fire off anther event saying "Program Created"

So the problem comes in at the middle. The Program service needs to know what programs which events it needs to be monitoring in order to know when to do it's final bit of work and then fire the "Program Created" event. We can't hard code this into the service, because that means that any time a new service is added (or removed) it would mean a code change to the Program service and we obviously don't want that.

So my thought is we could have some sort of registration service. All services would register with the registration service. In the case of the Program Service, it would say which events it provides ("Program Initialized" and "Program Created") as well as say it cares about which services consume the "Program Initialized" event. Any time another service is registered with the Registration Service and it says that it cares about the "Program Initialized" event, it will fire an event saying as such. The Program Service will see that and update a local list of services & events that it needs to keep track of before the "Program Created" event can be fired.

I initially thought this would be in the realm of Service Discovery/Service Registry, but from my reading, a Service Registry seems to be a lot more simplistic (just keeps a general list of services and their locations).

Is there some other pattern out there that can service this sort of way of doing things?

Comment: Suppose I create a Service X that consumes "Program Initialized" and provides 3 events "A", "B" and "C". How would the Program Service know which to wait for before it can fire "Program Created"?

Comment: I had thought about that and I figured that when a service registers with the registration service and gives a list of it's event, it could assign some sort of type to each event that it registers and the original service would be looking for that type.

Another way would be that we have this as some sort of sidecar for the Program service, so all the other services will register specifically with the Program's sidecar service, and when it does that it would say what the event is that is response specific "response" event to the one it's consuming.

Comment: What happens if you make the Program the registry too? (that's a Socratic question)